# On a company network, in Outlook 2007, can you add your own phone number to the global address book?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007

In Outlook 2007 on a company network, I can see my contact information with I select the To button on new email, and find myself in the address book.  The phone number is empty.  If I right-click and choose Properties, I can see all my information.  But it's not letting me edit this.

Is this something that is edited and saved elsewhere?  If so, where?  Or, is it something that only the Exchange Administor or some other admin can edit?

Comment: I beleive that's populated in AD? Try changing your info in the directory?

Comment: Does a ordinary user have access to AD?  How would I get to and change the info there?

Comment: Yeah, i shouldn't have assumed you were the admin. Yes,  have your admin update your info.

Comment: Make that an answer, and I'll accept it (after getting the admin to update the info, of course).